# Hide Horizontal Scroll bar in powershell

Tags: winforms, powershell, powershell-2.0

I have a tablelayoutpanel that I have autoscroll turn on for. I would like to completely hide the horizontal scroll bar but do not see how this is possible. It seems like I could set VScroll to true and HScroll to false but I am unsure how to access these properties from the tablelayoutpanel object. How can I hide the horizontal scroll bar?

```
[CmdletBinding()]

Param()

Set-StrictMode -Version 2
[void] [System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("System.Drawing") | Out-Null
[void] [System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("System.Windows.Forms") | Out-Null

Write-Verbose "Create the main form"
$form = New-Object Windows.Forms.Form
$form.Size = New-Object Drawing.Size @(900, 600)

$form.SuspendLayout()

$dataSize = 70
$dataHeight = 20
$volumeSize = 280
$dp = New-Object Windows.Forms.TableLayoutPanel
$addButton = New-Object Windows.Forms.Button
$addButton.Text = "Add"
$addButton.name = "outputButton"
$addButton.Add_Click({Add-Row})
$addButton.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Point(0,500)
$correctedWidth = 0

Function Add-Row ($txt) {

    write-verbose "add row"
    $script:dp.RowCount++
    $zeroBasedRow = $dp.RowCount - 1
    write-verbose $zeroBasedRow
    for ($i=0; $i -lt 7; $i++) {
        $label = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Label
        $label.TextAlign = "MiddleCenter"
        $label.Text = "0"
        $label.Font = "Verdana, 9pt"
        $label.Size = "$dataSize,$dataHeight"
        $label.BackColor = "Transparent"
        if ($i -eq 0) {
            $label.Size = "$correctedWidth,$dataHeight"
            if ($txt -eq $null){
                $label.Text = "12345678901234567890123456789012"
            } else {
                $label.Text = $txt
            }
        }
        $dp.Controls.Add($label,$i,$zeroBasedRow)
    }
}

Function Create-Data-Panel ($width, $height, $correction) {

    Write-Verbose "Create the panel that holds the data"
    $dataPanel = New-Object Windows.Forms.TableLayoutPanel
    $dataPanel.Size = New-Object Drawing.Size @($width,$height)
    $dataPanel.AutoScroll = $true
    #$dataPanel.VerticalScroll.Enabled = $true
    #$dataPanel.VerticalScroll.Visible = $true
    #$dataPanel.HorizontalScroll.Enabled = $false
    #$dataPanel.HorizontalScroll.Visible = $false
    $dataPanel.BackColor = "Transparent"
    $dataPanel.CellBorderStyle = "None"
    $dataPanel.RowCount = 0
    $dataPanel.ColumnCount = 7  

    $script:correctedWidth = $volumeSize - $correction

    return $dataPanel
}

$hght = $form.size.height * 3/4
$dp = Create-Data-Panel 760 300 4
for ($j=0; $j -lt 50; $j++){     # LINE OF INTEREST!!!!!!
    $txt = "$j 12345678901234567890123456789012"
    Add-Row $txt
}
$form.Controls.Add($dp)
$form.Controls.Add($addButton)

$form.Add_Shown( { $form.Activate() } )    
$form.ResumeLayout()
$form.StartPosition = "CenterScreen"    
$form.ShowDialog()
```

Notice that AutoScroll is on. If you run this script as is the TableLayoutPanel will only show the vertical scroll bar; push the "Add" button as many times as you want and you will see the table has new entries at the end and the scroll bar remains only showing the vertical scroll bar. The problem is that the TableLayoutPanel I am working with does not have ANY initial data on it so essentially the "LINE OF INTEREST!!!!!!" becomes a 0 for the $j bounding value. Change that value to zero so the line reads "for ($j=0; $j -lt 0; $j++){ # LINE OF INTEREST!!!!!!" and then run the script (notice the table is empty. Press the "Add" button (notice no scroll bars show up until they are needed which is not a problem). Fill the table so that the vertical scroll bar is needed and you will see that BOTH the vertical and horizontal scroll bars appear – I ONLY want the vertical scroll bar not the horizontal – so my question is how to hide the horizontal scroll bar? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that the scroll bars extend *inward* in the panel, decreasing the available space for the embedded controls.

Thus, once a *vertical* scrollbar is shown due to `.AutoScroll` being set to `$true`, there isn't enough horizontal space for the labels anymore, and the *horizontal* scrollbar is shown too.

With `.AutoScroll` set to `$true`, you cannot manually turn the scrollbars off with statements such as `.HorizontalScrollBar.Visble = $false` - such attempts are *ignored*.

*I'm sure there are better solutions*, but here's a *quick fix*, that:

- *widens* the panel by the width of the vertical scroll bar once the latter is shown, which causes `.AutoScroll` ultimately not to show a horizontal scrollbar,
- but note that that *the horizontal scrollbar will flash visibly* before it is hidden when the row that causes the vertical scroll bar to show is added.

```powershell
Function Add-Row ($txt) {
    write-verbose "Adding row with index $($dp.RowCount)"
    $dp.SuspendLayout()
    $dp.RowCount++
    for ($i=0; $i -lt 7; $i++) {
        $label = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Label
        $label.TextAlign = "MiddleCenter"
        $label.Text = "0"
        $label.Font = "Verdana, 9pt"
        $label.Size = "$dataSize,$dataHeight"
        $label.BackColor = "Transparent"
        if ($i -eq 0) {
            $label.Size = "$correctedWidth,$dataHeight"
            if ($txt -eq $null){
                $label.Text = "12345678901234567890123456789012"
            } else {
                $label.Text = $txt
            }
        }
        $dp.Controls.Add($label, $i, $dp.RowCount - 1)
    }    
    $dp.ResumeLayout()

    # If a horizontal scrollbar has just appeared as a follow-on effect
    # of AutoScroll having just turned on the vertical scrollbar,
    # widen the panel by the width of the vertical scrollbar 
    # so as to make the horizontal scrollbar disappear again.
    if ($dp.HorizontalScroll.Visible) {
        $dp.width += [System.Windows.Forms.SystemInformation]::VerticalScrollBarWidth
    }
}
```

---

On a side note: using both `[void]` and | `Out-Null` in the statements that load the assemblies is unnecessary and will actually fail in PSv5 (possibly 4 or 3 too).

Comment: So the TableLayoutPanel must be resized if the table is populated such that scroll bars are needed prior to displaying the form if possible (which in this case was possible since the horizontal bar was absent upon the form displaying)?

Comment: @user1759789: Resizing _in advance_ is _not_ an option, because, with the labels filling the entire panel, the appearance of the vertical scrollbar will always reduce the horizontal space, no matter how wide you make the panel itself. I don't know enough about WinForms to have the right answer, but looking into _nesting_ controls, such as: place the panel inside a scrolling container and leave a margin on the right, then make the container auto-scrollable.